# Read Access in Linux File System. rwx---r--

Tags: linux, file, system

Consider a file with the following permissions:

rwx---r--

I am not the owner of this file, but I am a member of the group of this file.

My question is: do I have read access to this file?

I thought the answer was YES, since the world has read access to this file. But, a sysadmin is telling me that the answer is NO, since the group access bits are all off.

Can someone provide an authoritative answer?

Comment: This belongs to serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drwxrwxr-x`

Position 1 says whether it is a directory or a normal file. `d` for directory and `-` for normal file

Positions 2,3 and 4 stands for read, write, execute permissions for user of the file.

Positions 5,6 and 7 stands for read, write, execute permissions for group.

Positions 8,9 and 10 stand for read, write, exeucte permissions for the owner of the file.

So for `rwx---r--`, group has no permissions as group bits are turned off.

Comment: Is it applicable to all the posix compliant systesm?

Comment: @Sanish: you forgot to mention that they evaluate left to right, and the first match wins.  So even if the file is world readable someone who's not the owner, but part of the owning group in this case, won't have read access DESPITE it being world-readable.